# I use vscode on Mac OS and it's being weird

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner coder and when I run my code it gives this. It prompts me to give an input but when I click on enter, nothing happens and I have to run the code again before it prints. I have installed code runner.

```
// my code 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){ 
    int no_eggs;
    printf("The total number of eggs gotten is: ");
    scanf("%i\n", &no_eggs);

    double dozen = no_eggs/12.0;
    printf("This gives %f dozen eggs\n", dozen);
    return 0;
}
```

the output in the terminal

```
kaye@mis-MacBook-Pro-455 \~ % cd "/Users/kaye/Desktop/" && gcc \*.c -o hello && "/Users/kaye/Desktop/"hello
The total number of eggs gotten is: 30
cd "/Users/kaye/Desktop/" && gcc *.c -o hello && "/Users/kaye/Desktop/"hello
This gives 2.500000 dozen eggs
```

Comment: VSCode is likely not involved. You can run the code in an independent terminal to check.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your newline in `scanf`. This is causing the program to wait for more input. Remove it and it works.

All whitespace in a `scanf` format is treated the same way. It will consume all whitespace and won't stop until it sees non-whitespace. When you type `30` and hit enter, `scanf` continues waiting for more input. Your code will work if you input, for example, `30   stop`. `scanf` will consume `30`    and then stop when it sees the `s`.

Why you're getting spurious output may be because when VSCode terminates the program it closes its input. When input closes `scanf` finally returns and the program can finally finish. It only looks like the print it coming from the second run.

See also: [`scanf` docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and [C FAQ about `scanf`](https://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

Comment: @beginnercoder You're welcome. scanf is tricky and often best avoided.